# Trying to pass user input in usecols Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to ask the user which columns do they want read in the dataframe from a csv file.
I've been trying the following:

```
    col = [0, 1]

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols = lambda x: x in col, index_col=False, header=1)
```

But even this gives an error. Any suggestions? I think so I'm not able to understand the lambda function.
The error I'm getting is:
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: In your example, you have extra spaces. Please try
`df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=lambda x: x in col, index_col=False, header=1)`

Comment: Also, wouldn't `df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=col, index_col=False, header=1)` do what you need to do?

Comment: Please post the first few lines from your filename so we can see if there are any issues with the file

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. Have you tried just `usecols=col` ?

Comment: Yup it worked using usecols=col, idk why but python deleted my excel files in the directory. Must have done it by mistake probably when I was debugging. That was the reason for the error! Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the col list as the answer to the usecols parameter.

```
col_list = [0, 1]
df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols = col_list, index_col=False, header=1)
```